# Child divs fails to get 100% height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a container 100% of my body height and then i want to have a header and textarea blocks with 10% and 90% of that height.

Here is a fiddle of my results and my code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muhyee/3hAqS/)

Notice that header only appears because of padding.

Also in my chrome explorer container doesn't get the 100% height of the body as the fiddle above.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <textarea autofocus id="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    min-width: 240px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 10%;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 22px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#textarea {
    background: yellow;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't added `height: 100%;` to your `#container`.

Also if you add padding to an element that is 100% width or height the element will overflow.
You should add padding to the child elements instead to get around this.

Comment: Yes that did the trick...Thanks. I noticed the overflow it was my next concern to solve, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

div is a block element an it takes only height of its content. So if you want it too be larger  you need to put values of height in px not in %. So in your case try

```
html, body {
height: 500px;
```

}

and

```
height: 800px;
```